# XPath: How do I find a page element which contains another element, using the full text of both?

Tags: xpath

I have an HTML page which contains the following:

```
<div class="book-info">
  The book is <i>Italicized Title</i> by Author McWriter
</div>
```

When I view this in Chrome Dev Tools, it looks like:

```
<div class="book-info">
  "The book is "
  <i>Italicized Title</i>
  " by Author McWriter"
</div>
```

I need a way to find this single div using XPath.

**Constraints:**

1. There are many `book-info` divs on the page, so I can't just look for a div with that class.
2. Any part of the text within the `book-info` div might also appear in another, but the complete text within the div is unique.  So I want to match the entire text, if possible.
3. It is not guaranteed that an `<i>` will exist within the `book-info` div.  The following could also exist, and I need to be able to find it as well (but my code is working for this case):

```
<div class="book-info">
  "Author McWriter's Legacy"
</div>
```

4. I think I can detect whether the `div` I'm looking for contains an `<i>` or not, and construct a different XPath expression depending on that.

**Things I have tried:**

1. `//div[text()=concat("The book is ","Italicized Title"," by Author McWriter")]`
2. `//div[text()=concat("The book is ","<i>Italicized Title"</i>," by Author McWriter")]`
3. `//div[text()=concat("The book is ",[./i[text()="Italicized Title"]," by Author McWriter")]`
4. `//div[concat(text()="The book is ", i[text()="Italicized Title"],text()=" by Author McWriter")]`

None of these worked for me. What XPath expression would?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this combination of XPath-1.0 predicates in one expression. It matches both cases:

```
//div[@class="book-info" and ((i and contains(text()[1],"The book is") and contains(text()[2],"by Author McWriter")) or (not(i) and contains(string(.),"Author McWriter&apos;s Legacy")))]
```